# Iterative calculus with Excel

Tags: calculus, optimization, mathematical-modeling

I have this model:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\textrm{max}[(0.2(1.07)^{-1}+0.2(1.07)^{-2}+0.9(1.07)^{-3})x_{A}+(0.4(1.07)^{-1}+0.5(1.07)^{-2}+0.3(1.07)^{-3})x_{B}]\\ 0.2x_{A}+0.4x_{B}\geq300.000
\\ 
0.2x_{A}+0.5x_{B}\geq400.000\\x_{A}+x_{B}=1.000.000 
\\x_{A},x_{B}\geq0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I have to find $x_{A}$ and $x_{B}$ with Excel. I'm inexperienced: how do I set up the program to use the iterative calculus? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is probably the wrong site for an Excel question.  Given you're trying to model using Excel *maybe* [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: Put "linear program in excel" in Youtube.